# android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED Intent is not received at "Restart" or "Reboot"

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

Android `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` Intent is not received if I use the **"Restart"** or **"Reboot"**, but works if I turn off and on the device. Is there Any way to make this work?

Comment: Add "                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
"  also.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Add

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
```

also

Comment: This is for broadcast receiver? Thanks!

Comment: Just a doubt may be a little off topic but will the alarm set by an app need to be reset after a reboot/restart? Please help I am not very much familiar with Android.

Comment: @RajeshK Restart in Broadcast receiver.

Comment: Thanks. But since Android 8 only `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast is allowed? How should I solve this issue? Since `QUICKBOOT_POWERON` is not longer allowed.

Comment: Is there any reference to QUICKBOOT_POWERON in the official documentation ? I searched but couldn't find one. But it works, I added it myself in the manifest and the code and Android recognized it.

Comment: yes, @RajeshK I also desperately need to reregister notifications the user scheduled....or perhaps send notifications from servers to FCM api to have phone reregister daily in case a reboot?  I am not sure how to do this as users won't be happy since they scheduled the reminder to go off.

Comment: Is this still useful nowadays to use `android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON` ? If not, from which API ?

Answer (score 6):

Kindly add the below Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

and add the Receiver Class entry in manifest.zml:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.receivers.BootReceiver" >
```

Now Receiver Class:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  private static final String TAG = "Boot Receiver:::";
   /*
    * (non-Javadoc)
    * 
    * @see android.content.BroadcastReceiver#onReceive(android.content.Context,
    * android.content.Intent)
    */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      if (intent != null) {
        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(
                Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {

            //Boot Receiver Called
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

Now Clean and Run your Application. Hope This class will be called after you power on/off or restarting the device. let me know your feedback.

Comment: that's what I've originally did.

Comment: then this will work perfectly.. put log in onReceive.. and test it.. else post your manifest and receiver class

Comment: <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" /> is the solution Giru Bhai already exposed.

Comment: Where does the Receiver class go, please?

Answer (score 3):

Add `<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />` this permission in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

add `android:priority="100"`, launch `onReceive` approximately through 30с

```
<receiver android:name="..." android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="100">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

And inside you "application" block:

```
<receiver
    android:label="SystemEventReceiver"
    android:name=".SystemEventReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
        <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_UNSUSPENDED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Make sure `android:exported="false"` and not "true" or the system will not send the broadcast to your app.