# Difference between BOOT_COMPLETED and QUICKBOOT_POWERON on Android

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have created BroadcastReceiver to schedule my Service execution every 30 seconds. This is what I have in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<receiver android:name="MyScheduleReceiver" >
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This is working great now, but only after I added QUICKBOOT_POWERON action. Before that I had only BOOT_COMPLETED and when I reboot emulator or phone while debugging, my service would never start. So my question is what is the difference between these two and when to use each?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978403/boot-receiver-not-work

Comment: That's exactly where I found working solution - but my phone is not HTC and it still wasn't working without QUICKBOOT_POWERON. That's the reason why I opened new question in order to get more general answer.

Comment: com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON (and not android.intent.action...)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692923/any-way-to-know-if-device-booted-from-a-fastboot

Answer (score 28):

Intent `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` is received after a "cold" boot.

Intent `android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON` is received after a "restart" or a "reboot".

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882861/android-intent-action-boot-completed-intent-is-not-received-at-restart-or-reb)

Comment: I restarted my phone (Lenovo P2) an received a Boot_completed intent... didn't check the other one though.

Comment: I think it's applicable only for Google emulator. Real devices always do "cold" boot

Comment: Is this still useful nowadays to use `android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON` ? If not, from which API ?

Comment: But that permission is not anywhere! Where actually did people heard of this permissio? Should it even be used if Android Studio doesn't find it?? I have internal/hidden APIs showing and it still doesn't exist, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

This is only required on HTC devices to support their "quickboot" feature

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
```

Here is the full code from official code
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/StorageManager/+/refs/tags/android-7.1.2_r8/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".automatic.AutomaticStorageBroadcastReceiver"
                      android:enabled="@bool/enable_automatic_storage_management">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    <!-- This is required on HTC devices to support their "quickboot" feature -->
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
enter code here
```